# Не могу понять в чем проблема с Vuex, пишет Error in render: «TypeError»?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

**Ввожу адрес в командной строке браузера http://localhost:8080/product/1**

Не могу никак понять, почему когда я распечатываю объект **{{loadProduct}}**, распечатывается без проблем,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
а когда указываю какое-то свойство объекта **{{loadProduct.price}}**, то в консоле получаю ошибку, но при этом свойство выводится на экран.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кто знает подскажите пожалуйста.
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Выложите код текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: написано же 'property "*" of undefined' т.е. ты запрашиваешь свойство у переменной которая еще не объявлена, видимо в тот момент store пустой. Нужно добавить проверку на пустоту {{typeof loadProduct !== 'undefined' ? loadProduct.price : ''}}

Comment: Спасибо, понял!